# sum column in case expressions

Tags: mysql, select, sum, case

I want if the users age>20 ,Columns1 and columns2 sum Gather and show
I wrote the following code but error:
`SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age>20  THEN col1+col2+col3 ELSE 0 END) AS 'result1', 
SUM(CASE WHEN age=20  THEN col1+col2+col3 ELSE 0 END) AS 'result2', 
SUM(CASE WHEN age<20  THEN col1+col2+col3 ELSE 0 END) AS 'result3'
FROM users`

how to solve this??

Comment: use double quotes or backticks for column names, not single quotes

Comment: For future reference when posting errors; be sure to include the error text and expected results.

Comment: tank you @quassnoi . solve by add  quotes

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, I think you need more parenthesis first, I don't know why you are quoting the column names, so I dropped that.

```
SELECT 
SUM((CASE WHEN age > 20 THEN col1 + col2 + col3 ELSE 0 END)) as result1,
SUM((CASE WHEN age = 20 THEN col1 + col2 + col3 ELSE 0 END)) as result2,
SUM((CASE WHEN age > 20 THEN col1 + col2 + col3 ELSE 0 END)) as result3
FROM
"users"
```

Comment: Case statements don't require parenthesis.  The sum does.  No need to double up on the ()'s